# Visual Basic connect database with ODBC setting with register

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, odbc, registry

I have the code written to connect to the ODBC registry.
The database name is written to the combobox.
I need to transfer my ip address and password from ODBC.ini to the connect string after selecting the database from the combobox.
This is a connection to MYSQL.

Thank you

```
Private Sub DsnLookup()

    Dim dsnNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim reg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software")

    If reg IsNot Nothing Then
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC")
        If reg IsNot Nothing Then
            reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI")
            If reg IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each dsn As String In reg.GetSubKeyNames
                    dsnNames.Add(dsn)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If


    For Each Name As String In dsnNames
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Name)
    Next Name


End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DsnLookup()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connString As String = "Database='combobox data;Data Source='ip adres odbc;" _
    & "User Id=root;Password=' odbc PWD"
```

Comment: Is it connecting to a datasource on the local PC each time?  If so, could you use hostname 'localhost' instead of finding local IP address?

Comment: no , ip adresy are remote computers.Bud se připojím na místní databázi "localhost" nebo vyberu vzdálený počítač  . Ip adresu mám napsanou v odbc a název je  firm_stanice2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Server Name (or IP) and Database name from the ODBC.INI but it doesn't store the password.  Either include a master password in your connectionstring (securely of course) or look into other authentication options.

This is how to get the Database and Server info from the registry.  Keeping your code the same, but replacing the Button1.Click event and adding an additional function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then  'Make sure something from dropdown selected

        Dim connString As String = String.Format("Database='{0}';Data Source='{1}';User Id=root;", GetODBCValue(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Database"), GetODBCValue(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Server"))

    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetODBCValue(ByVal ODBCName As String, ByVal ValueName As String) As String

    Dim reg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software")
    reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC")
    reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI")
    reg = reg.OpenSubKey(ODBCName)
    Return reg.GetValue(ValueName)

End Function
```

Comment: thank you . i use this code  Dim connString As String = String.Format("Database='{0}';Data Source='{1}';PWD='{2}';User Id=root;", GetODBCValue(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Database"), GetODBCValue(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Server"),GetODBCValue(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "PWD"));

Comment: I didn't have a PWD stored on mine, so good to hear you're sorted.  If this answer helped, could you mark it as the solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer

I tried to edit it

```
    Private Function GetODBCValu(ByVal ODBCName As String, ByVal ValueName As String) As String
        Dim dsnNames As New List(Of String)
        Dim reg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software")
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC")
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI")
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey(ODBCName)
        Return reg.GetValue(ValueName)

        For Each dsn As String In reg.GetSubKeyNames
            dsnNames.Add(dsn)
        Next
        For Each Name As String In dsnNames
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Name)
        Next Name

    End Function
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

 Dim connString As String = String.Format("Database='{0}';Data Source='{1}';User Id=root;", GetODBCValu(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Database"), GetODBCValu(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "Server"))
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
```

Try
            Call conecDB()
            dt = New DataTable 's_table
         Dim con As New SqlConnection

```
        DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        DateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        DateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn       
 da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("select --- ", connDB)


        comBuilderDB = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(dt)
        dbvypis.DataSource = dt



        conn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("COMPLET")

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try

    Try
        'declaring variable as integer to store the value of the total rows in the datagridview

        Dim max As Integer = dbvypis.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim total As String = "TOTAL ----->"
        Dim TOTALCOST As Integer = 0
        'getting the values of a specific rows


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dbvypis.Rows
            'formula for adding the values in the rows
            TOTALCOST += row.Cells(1).Value
        Next
        dbvypis.Rows(max).Cells(1).Value += TOTALCOST
        dbvypis.Rows(max).Cells(0).Value = total

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

It occurred to me that if I select a database in the comboboxu so it gets into ODBC and connString to the command adds the server and database name

Then it writes to me in the result Index is out of range, Index must be non-negative and must be smaller than the collection size. Parameter name: index